# awk regex: Help matching CSV file that has fields with comma within double quotes

Tags: regex, csv, awk

Need your help !!!

I have an input file 1.txt as follows:

```
"row1@abc.com,venki@abc.com,vr@xyz.com",field2,field3,field4
row2r@xyz.com,field2,field3,field4
field1,"row3@abc.com,venki@abc.com, vr@xyz.com",field3,field4
field1,"1111@abc.com,row4@abc.com",,field4
field1,"1111@abc.com""1234,999,row5@abc.com",,field4
```

I want to identify rows that do not have exactly four(4) columns and remove them from the file before loading to a PostGres Table using the copy command.

I am using awk as follows:

awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)||("[^"]+")||(^[ ]*$)' '{printf("Row:%d,NF=%d, %s, %s, %s, %s\n",NR, NF, $1,$2,$3,$4)}' 1.txt

And the output is;

```
Row:1,NF=4, "row1@abc.com,venki@abc.com, vr@xyz.com", field2, field3, field4
Row:2,NF=4, row2r@xyz.com, field2, field3, field4
Row:3,NF=4, field1, "row3@abc.com,venki@abc.com, vr@xyz.com", field3, field4
Row:4,NF=4, field1, "1111@abc.com,row4@abc.com", , field4
Row:5,NF=6, field1, "1111@abc.com""1234, 999, row5@abc.com"
```

You can see the problem with the last row. It has both double quotes and two commas in the value and that is screwing things up. The NF for that row is 6 when it should be 4.

Can anyone suggest the regex to identify the value 
"1111@abc.com""1234,999,row5@abc.com"

Thanks. Venki

Comment: Just to be clear the value "1111@abc.com""1234,999,row5@abc.com" is a valid value, only problem is that it has double quotes and comma in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for solving your problem can be, change the quoted regex part from `("[^"]+")` to `(".+")` which will allow it to capture quoted text including comma and double quote and actually any character. And also, change the order of regex in alternations. Basically, change your regex from this,

```
([^,]+)||("[^"]+")||(^[ ]*$)
```

to,

```
(".+")||([^,]+)||(^[ ]*$)
```

This way, it will first attempt to capturing a quoted data (based upon first regex `(".+")`), and will capture `"1111@abc.com""1234,999,row5@abc.com"` where as earlier it was trying to capture this `"1111@abc.com"` because your regex was `("[^"]+")` which won't allow any double quote or comma to get captured inside the data. So this should fix your capturing problem.

Upon actually running this command,

```
awk -v FPAT='(".+")||([^,]+)||(^[ ]*$)' '{printf("Row:%d,NF=%d, %s, %s, %s, %s\n",NR, NF, $1,$2,$3,$4)}' awk.txt
```

on your file data `1.txt1` as mentioned in your post, I got following output, which hopefully should be correct as you expected.

```
Row:1,NF=4, "row1@abc.com,venki@abc.com,vr@xyz.com", field2, field3, field4
Row:2,NF=4, row2r@xyz.com, field2, field3, field4
Row:3,NF=4, field1, "row3@abc.com,venki@abc.com, vr@xyz.com", field3, field4
Row:4,NF=4, field1, "1111@abc.com,row4@abc.com", , field4
Row:5,NF=4, field1, "1111@abc.com""1234,999,row5@abc.com", , field4
```

Let me know if this works for you?

Comment: Absolute genius, worked like a charm!!!, I was almost there but not quite there and that is the difference you all make. You saved my hide, thanks so much. Will close the issue now.

Comment: @user3579374: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - it did create one more problem. There is one more field with the same pattern. And so now it is considering everything in-between the first double quote " to the last double quote in the row and identifying them as one field. Basically my problem is to identify one field as anything that starts with a double quote, ends with a double-quote and then followed by a comma. Imagine $3 == $2 in the last row, can we still get NF == 4 for that row?

Comment: @VenkiR: Yes, that will be a problem if you have such kind of data in more than one column, because it `".+"` is a greedy capture and it will capture everything until last `"`. One work around can be to make it non-greedy capture and have a positive look ahead to stop as soon as `"` is immediately followed by a comma but I don't think look aheads are supported in AWK. However, in that case, you may try using Perl for same. Let me know if you need me to help with a Perl based solution.

Comment: Pushpesh: For now, I did some pre-processing with sed and removed all occurrences of "", and went back to my previous regex FPAT='([^,]+)||("[^"]+")||(^[ ]*$)' and that seems to work. So I will accept your answer and close the issue, thanks for all the help. Much appreciated!!!!